# "Нечищеный" или "нечищенный"

Tags: правописание, прилагательные, орфография

Согласно информации о правописании бесприставочных прилагательных и причастий с `-н-` и `-нн-`, которую я нашел в Интернете, прилагательные должны писаться с `-н-`, а причастия - с `-нн-`. Например,

```
чищеный - прилагательное
чищенный - причастие
```

(например, [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/48622/%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%9D%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%9D%D0%9D%D1%8B%D0%B9))

В то же время, появление приставки приводит к тому, что и прилагательное пишется с `-нн-`, за исключением приставки `не-`, которая, согласно найденным мною правилам, на правописание `-н-`/`-нн-` не влияет.

Отсюда я делаю вывод, что орфографически правильными должны являться обе формы с приставкой `не-`

```
нечищеный - прилагательное
нечищенный - причастие
```

Прав ли я? Я замечаю, в частности, что программа проверки правописания в Google Chrome принимает слова `чищеный`, `чищенный` и `нечищеный`, но отвергает слово `нечищенный`.

Если поведение Chrome верно, то какие правила я упустил в своих рассуждениях? Существует ли в русском языке слово `нечищенный`? И если нет, то почему.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Вы правы: приставка "не" и с причастиями в определенных случаях пишется слитно. ***По ссылке - правило.*** 
[Справочник по правописанию и стилистике. — М.: Комплект. Д. Э. Розенталь. 1997.](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=783.U3KU0_y7VORo3G9k58l1w6PA271ER8UFSRF98EdnnjLC_gZ5VZASm7wiQJVZBEqUBlHrrt-pbsznkgeRJE53JQ.b1ee9913f0c1f0e858dbe839f2caa60409943540&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9WCnKp0DidhEr16RFjt_h9kMwOKhK2Pw7RlTkiUNpvm1IbsdiJHd8tA&data=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&b64e=2&sign=52842d2c0dd675f6f81c5e87dc182617&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5Hyx_fyvalFPA9KI5rmKu0WS7bRgCElMxpwHW8czAf5ulH3IZ7RVvKGzB-CgOG2SS104jLVxcYhkg4RSAWpRJM9c1uQBhvUjhwh6MeROfwYRzmchUM0eeGaGybDaqMLyIVMxjyp08VTx3Iv1YZTSdAQ9kWyDJontMHcNlRvq2AA6lD9mXtou-DbGjc_hlhuFXlnKMwn_RoXQ&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHpMQ80108_UCTdwuV_bvPyfSQ3Wu39WHEQuhu8kJcY3-9D4MQJ-e8QNvkrwukeYpWfV0JCzuRcrfz3Tmc42Ir9bmCUNSkL00EaxxfO6-OloLccIpjBOYYVoTex0S4rzMKTlIQjhjC6pCSCwx4WlZYw0jXY0B0qy1l6q71PEfrl250VTEfjxxQ2KbTNyihh-hLeuzOUlq1cWS&l10n=ru&cts=1439789880664&mc=4.324625008845896)

- **Дополнение**

В данном случае перед нами глагол несовершенного вида. Причастия этих глаголов и прилагательные пишутся по-разному: если есть зависимые слова - причастие, нет зависимых слов - прилагательное. 
Ср.: жареная рыба ( прилагательное), жаренная на сковородке рыба (причастие). 
Чищеные туфли, чищенные ваксом туфли (причастие).

Пишется раздельно ***не*** с причастиями, имеющими ***при себе пояснительные слова,*** например: ***не возвращённая автору рукопись***, не замеченные корректором опечатки, не сданные в срок гранки

Comment: Да, я знаю. Но вопрос не о приставке `не-`. Вопрос о правописании суффикса. Фактически: существует ли в русском языке слово `нечищенный`. И если нет, то почему мне не разрешается добавить приставку `не-` к заведомо существующему причастию `чищенный`.

Comment: Вы говорите, что "если есть зависимые слова - причастие, нет зависимых слов - прилагательное". Но вот эта страница - http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.56 - не согласна с таким правилом и приводит примеры причастий без зависимых слов: *невыполненная работа, невычитанная рукопись, недвигающийся объект, непрочитанная книга*. Заметьте, что один из глаголов - тоже несовершенного вида.

Comment: В данном случае два вида причастий: действительные и страдательные . Последние образованы от глаголов совершенного вида. Невыполненная  - от выполнить , невычитанная - от вычитать,  недвигающийся - от надвигаться( несовершенный вид, но: ***действительное причастие***). Чищенный - образовано от глагола несовершенного вида.

Comment: Обратите также внимание: причастия, о которых идет речь, всегда бесприставочные.

Comment: Вы просто констатируете факты, но к чему - мне не ясно. "Чищенный - образовано от глагола несовершенного вида". И? Какое правило, применимое, к нашему случаю, делит причастия по виду глагола? "Причастия, о которых идет речь, всегда бесприставочные". "Идет речь" где, в каком правиле?

Comment: Что не ясного? Эти причастия образуются от бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида. Отличия этих причастий от прилагательных в том, что причастия образуются только при наличии пояснительных слов, а приставка "не" ,как известна, при наличии пояснительных слов пишется раздельно с причастиями.

Comment: См. Академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина. ДЭ.Розенталь. Справочник по пунктуации.

Comment: Не ясно вот что: "Эти причастия образуются от бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида". Какие "эти" причастия имеются в виду? О каком правиле идет речь? В каком случае "причастия образуются только при наличии пояснительных слов"?

Comment: Вы же говорите о бесприставочных глаголах.  Вот и я о них.

Comment: Еще рез: скажите мне, где сказано, что бесприставочный глагол несовершенного вида может порождать причастие только в присутствии пояснительных слов? Я считал, что прилагательное отличается от причастия только способом употребления, т.е. смысловым значением, заложенным автором текста.

Comment: Вот и Розенталь говорит: "Разграничение страдательных причастий и образованных от них прилагательных (тем самым выбор написания нн или н) иногда производится не по формальному признаку, а по смысловому значению. Например- в предложении *Будучи раненным, солдат оставался в строю* в слове *раненным* пишется нн, несмотря на отсутствие приставки и пояснительных слов: оно сохраняет глагольное значение, указывает не на постоянный признак-качество, а на временное состояние, т. е. является причастием.".

Comment: чищенные ваксом туфли (причастие). Есть зависимое слово (ваксом). Чищенные туфли - прилагательное.

Comment: Нет, нет, нет, ни в коем случае. "Чищеные туфли" - прилагательное, передает значение устойчивого свойства: "чистые" туфли ("блестящие" туфли и т.п.). "Чищенные туфли" - причастие, передает значение изменяемого состояния: "туфли, которые уже почистили, в отличие от туфель, которые еще не чистили". Никакого наличия зависимых слов не требуется.

Comment: Причастия не на -ованный (-ёванный, -еванный) глаголов несовершенного вида (они образуются Только от бесприставочных глаголов) и соотносительные с ними прилагательные пишутся по-разному: причастия с нн, прилагательные — с одним н, напр.:

Comment: гружённые дровами повозки, жаренная на масле рыба, писанная маслом картина, стриженные парикмахером волосы и коротко стриженные волосы, крашенные зелёной краской скамейки, давно не метённый пол, ещё не белённые стены, уже не раз считанные деньги, деланное много раз предложение;

Comment: но: гружёная баржа, жареная рыба, писаная красавица, стриженые волосы, крашеные скамейки, метёный пол, белёные стены, считаные минуты, деланое равнодушие; аналогично вязанный и вязаный, глаженный и глаженый, плетённый и плетёный, ***чищенный и чищеный***; так же пишутся: жёванный и жёваный, клёванный и клёваный, кованный и кованый.

Comment: [Двойное н и одно н в суффиксах страдательных причастий прошедшего времени и соотносительных с ними прилагательных](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=52#pp52)

Comment: Совершенно верно - это именно то, с чего я начал. Зачем вы целиком копируете сюда все это, мне не ясно. Эта ссылка - это и есть источник моего вопроса.

Comment: Чтобы вы поняли.

Comment: Я скопировал правило, чтобы вы убедились сами. Я опираюсь на правило, а не выдумываю из себя.

Comment: Нет, нет. Вы что-то не понимаете. То, что написано по вашей ссылке в точности согласуется с тем, что говорю я. "Чищеный" - прилагательное, "чищенный" причастие. Какое из этих правил говорит, что причастие "чищенный" требует зависимого слова? Покажите мне его?

Comment: Только причастие: чищенные ваксом туфли (причастие). "Чищеные туфли" - прилагательные. Таково правило.

Comment: Где вы увидели такое правило? Среди того, что вы только что сюда накопировали такого правила нет.

Comment: Неужели вы не видите? Пройдитесь по ссылке. Столько примеров, а вы - не видите.

Comment: Как видно из примеров, причастие опознается по наличию зависимых слов. Бывают, однако, редкие случаи, когда зависимое слово не является признаком причастия. Напр., следует писать: у него усики явно крашеные (ср. явно искусственные, где слово явно употреблено при прилагательном); стены, раньше белёные, теперь покрыты зелёной краской (ср. стены, раньше белые).

Comment: Еще раз: среди того, что вы только что сюда накопировали такого правила нет. А "примерами" ничего не доказывается. Примеры могут только иллюстрировать правило. Пока что я нашел единственное релевантное правило у Розенталя - я процитировал его выше - и оно полностью подтверждает мою точку зрения.

Comment: Доказательством может являться только *контрпимер*, и я их вам уже приводил: недвигающися объект, раненный солдат - причастия. Никаких зависимых слов не надо.

Comment: Вы не читаете то, что я пишу. Наоборот, пытаетесь доказать того, чего нет.

Comment: Вот примечание к правилу( из справочника Лопатина). Как видно из примеров, причастие опознается по наличию зависимых слов. Бывают, однако, редкие случаи, когда зависимое слово не является признаком причастия. Напр., следует писать: у него усики явно крашеные (ср. явно искусственные, где слово явно употреблено при прилагательном); стены, раньше белёные, теперь покрыты зелёной краской (ср. стены, раньше белые).

Comment: Обратите внимание: иногда производится не по формальному признаку, а по смысловому значению.  Т.е. такое разграничение не всегда можно применить. Лишь в редких случаях.

Comment: недвигающися объект - действительное причастие, а не страдательное. Вы не хотите читать то, что вам пишут. Я привожу официальное правило.

Comment: Розенталь: . В суффиксах страдательных причастий прошедшего времени пишется нн; как правило, ***эти причастия имеют приставки или пояснительные слова***: исправленная рукопись; правленные корректором гранки.

***При отсутствии приставок или пояснительных слов пишется одно н***В этом случае перед нами прилагательное, образованное от страдательного причастия прошедшего времени: правленый текст, бешеный волк, вяленая вобла, глаженые брюки, драная куртка, золочёные изделия, ломаная линия, путаный ответ, рваная рана, сеяные травы, стираное бельё.

Comment: Читайте дальше в том же месте! Цитирую еще раз. Розенталь: "**Разграничение страдательных причастий и образованных от них прилагательных (тем самым выбор написания нн или н) иногда производится не по формальному признаку, а по смысловому значению**. Например- в предложении *Будучи раненным, солдат оставался в строю* в слове раненным пишется нн, несмотря на отсутствие приставки и пояснительных слов: оно сохраняет глагольное значение, **указывает не на постоянный признак-качество, а на временное состояние, т. е. является причастием**."

Comment: Иногда!!!!!!!! Это не значит, что всегда. В фразе: чищенные туфли нет временного признака.

Comment: Зачем вы пытаетесь подогнать ваш пример под это правило?

Comment: При слове раненный - есть слово Будучи - что придает временной оттенок и делает причастием.

Comment: Это не фраза. Это фрагмент фразы. Кто сказал, что в полном предложении его нет? Например: "Нечищеные яблоки полезнее чищеных" - это прилагательное, пишем одно "н". "С салат кладут картофель без шкурки, но варить картофель для салата надо варить нечищенным" - это причастие, подчеркивающее то, что сначала надо сварить картофель, а только потом почистить.

Comment: "Подогнать"? Во-первых, в примере с картофелем выше никакой "подгонки" нет. Есть смысловые значения, который должен передать автор текста. Выбор прилагательного или причастия *однозначно* определяется требуемым смыслом - признак или временное состояние (см. Розенталь). Во-вторых, мой вопрос довольно однозначен: есть ли в русском языке слово "нечищенный". Даже если мы захотим что-то под что-то "подогнать" - это не запрещается.

Comment: В словарях  нечищеный - прилагательное. Не чищенный - причастие.

Comment: Это интересно. Посмотрим словари... Хотя к сожалению, статистические доказательства - неприемлемы. "Нечищеный картофель" - прилагательное. "Нечищенный картофель" и "не чищенный ножом картофель" - причастия. Как только появилось зависимое слово - "не" отделяется. Но наличия зависимого слова не требуется. Мой пример "В салат кладут картофель без шкурки, но варить картофель для салата надо нечищенным" - совершенно корректен.

Comment: В вашим примере "варят нечищенным - значит в нечищеным виде" - это прилагательное, а не причастие. Даже компьютер не воспринимает "нечищенный".

Comment: См. скриншот  в основном ответе.

Comment: "Даже компьютер не воспринимает "нечищенный" - это мне не интересно. С этого собственно и начался мой вопрос. Более того, компьютер (как и любой контекстно-независимый словарь) не умеет различать части речи, ибо отличие прилагательного от причастия является частью авторского намерения.

Comment: Еще раз: мне нужно доказательство того, что слово "нечищенный" не может быть корректным причастием в рамках вышепроцитированного мною правила из Розенталя.

Comment: Кстати, орфографическая комиссия хотела унифицировать такие написание, как:  чищенный картофель и чищенный ножом картофель. Т.е. в обоих случаях писать одно н. Но: многие лингвисты не согласились.  Теперь имеем то правило, которое я привел.

Comment: Если писать так, как говорите вы, тогда можно писать: жареный картофель и жаренный картофель.

Comment: Вы привели половину правила из Розенталя. Я вам привел вторую половину этого правила. Меня интересуют *именно* рамки свободы, предоставляемой второй половиной этого правила. Вы это упорно игнорируете.

Comment: Я уже вам ответил.

Comment: В этом и вопрос! Имеет ли автор право воспользоваться тем же принципом, что использован у Розенталя я примере с "раненным солдатом", чтобы написать "жаренный картофель"?

Comment: Вы ответили лишь тем, что обвинили меня в подгонке моего примера под правило. Но меня именно и интересует формальная возможность такой подгонки.

Comment: Такие написание встречаются не всегда.  И то, примеры, которые мы имеем, образованы от глаголов совершенного вида. топленная печь - топленное масло. Это пример подпадает под пункт, где говорится, что разграничение причастий происходит по смысловому значению.

Comment: Заметьте, еще раз повторю: смысловое разграничение происходит ***ИНОГДА!***

Comment: Я уже ответил. В правилах четко сказано: чищенный - причастие, чищеный - прилагательное. Если вам не нравится это правило, ничего вам сказать больше не могу! правила пишу не я!

Comment: В этом и вопрос! Имеет ли автор право воспользоваться тем же принципом, что использован у Розенталя я примере с "раненным солдатом", чтобы написать "жаренный картофель"   Ответ на вопрос: НЕТ!!!!!

Comment: Вот, кстати, еще одна интересная статья, говрящая *именно* и *точно* о том, что я имею в виду: http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.72. Читать надо всю, но самое релевантное - на странице 4. Да, автор утверждает, что писать правильно  "жареный картофель", но по его словам "жареный" в данном случае это именно *причастие*, употребеленное **как** прилагательное. Более того, он уверждает, что одно -н- употреблено именно из трудности проникновения варианта -нн- в книжно-письменный язык. А вот настоящим прилагательным "жареный" становится в примерах типа "самый жареный кратофель" и "сильно жареный картофель".

Comment: Далее он говорит об отличиях и границах между академической грамматикой и догматическим школьными правилами. Мой выпрос - это вопрос именно академической грамматики. А вы постоянно забрасывете меня неперывным потоком школьных правил.

Comment: Правила, которые я привожу, не предназначены для школьников. Они взяты из справочников. Вы сами говорите: "Да, автор утверждает, что писать правильно "жареный картофель".

Comment: Это лишь мнение, правильность или неправильность которого я не отрицаю. Я лишь говорю, что согласно правилам, причастия, о которых идет речь, имеют при себя зависимые слова, прилагательные  - нет.

Comment: Правило, кстати, одно для всех.

Comment: Это замечательно. Но я задаю мой вопрос не потому, что вот "сейчас сижу сочинение пишу, завтра сдавать, и вот хочу по быстрому проверить одно словечко". Меня интересуют именно академические внутренние законы словообразования языка, которые привели к той или иной ситуации. "Правила" же - это совсем другое. Правила - это не более чем попытка анализа статистики для выработки компактных механических критериев правописания для обывателей. Именно потому, что не все случаи хорошо ложатся в общую статистику, правила имеют исключения.

Comment: Еще раз повторюсь: чищенный пишется по общему правилу. Автор приводит свою точку зрения, с которой другие могут не согласиться.  Я же привожу официально действующее правило.

Comment: Такие исключения, как раненый -раненный, топленый -топленный - редки. А автор статьи утверждает, что это единственные исключение.  Я уже писал, но вы, видимо, не прочли. Орфографическая комиссия хотела унифицировать такие написание, как: чищенный картофель и чищенный ножом картофель. Т.е. в обоих случаях писать одно н. Но: многие лингвисты не согласились. Теперь имеем то правило, которое я привел.

Comment: @AnT и Серж: интересно было прочитать вашу дискуссию. С одной стороны, понятна точка зрения AnT: совершенно ясно, что есть различие между соответствующими прилагательными и причастиями, а значит, -н- / -нн- должны его отражать. С другой стороны, Серж опирается на правила. Проблема здесь, как мне кажется, в том, что Розенталь и другие стараются этот вопрос обойти стороной.

Comment: Почему - я понял, когда прочитал § 63 Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации. В отличие от остальных, он очень нечеткий. Непонятно, имеется ли в виду, что в отсутствие зависимых слов наречие теряет свои глагольные свойства, или адъективация имеет все-таки семантическую, а не грамматическую природу.